18th century Reading Aristotle at in latin version and the search for translation biases
Philosophers of the 18th century, mainly those of the scholastic tradition and Kant, used to read Aristotle in its Latin translation, which is clearly clear from the citations. The Latin version of Aristotle, however, has several distortions and biases aimed at medieval religious traditions and philosophical currents. Some things are notoriously wrong or oversimplified. Aristotle is such a giant philosopher that many times when we think he is wrong, we discover that it is a translation error. That said, I would like to know from you, to better understand these biases, if there is a consensus on exactly what text they used as a translation of Aristotle in the 18th century and if this text is available today, perhaps on the internet.
